# Showing next tabpage from the 1st tab page in the tabControl in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have the two tabpages A,B in the tabcontrol in the windows form, and I want to show the tabpage B from the tabpage A on clicking the 'NEXT' button, How Should i do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `nextButton.Click` event, fire off the below code:

```
tabControl.SelectedTab = tabB;
```